# Python: to deal the case when the returned value is a large structure

Tags: python

if the returned value is a very large structure, like a list with millions of elements, 
how to deal such cases?

like

```
x=set[()]
def f(x):
     ....
     ....
     # now x has millions of elements
     return x
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with the data? What errors are you getting from what you've tried?

Comment: Aside from the `TypeError` on the first line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. you meant

   x = set()
2. the function acting on x does not need to return x, it can modify the passed value.
3. there is no duplication of data when you return a list or any other object... just because the value passed is not copied.
4. you are affected by the *premature optimization* syndrome since you are trying to solve an optimization problem before testing that the problem actually holds.

Example of function modifying a set:

```
>>> def f(x):
...   x.add(42)
... 
>>> x = set([13])
>>> x
set([13])
>>> f(x)
>>> x
set([42, 13])
```

Comment: right. But if he writes set[()] i think he means set([]) which by the way is equivalent to set()

Comment: for 2, I tried but the value is not modified

Comment: >>> def f(x):
...     x=set([3,4])
... 
>>> x=set([1,2])
>>> x
set([1, 2])
>>> f(x)
>>> x
set([1, 2])

Comment: @lily: it is better if you add the code in your question... it is difficult to read here

Comment: your function is not modifying the given set x, it is creating a new set.

Comment: so how to modify the set x?

Comment: you mean the "=" actually creates a new set?

Comment: the command set(...) creates a new set.

Comment: so for this function `def f(x): x=[3,4]`  if input `x=[1,2]`, x is sitll not modified. In this case, you mean `[]` creates a new list?

Comment: yes, exactly... You should imagine that x is a pointer to a set, not a set.